# \copyright producing TS1 version of symbol by default

Tags: fonts

I just updated my LaTeX system, and it seems that now `\copyright` is producing the TS1 version of the symbol by default. I mean that the file

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\copyright

\end{document}
```

produces what looks like the TS1 copyright symbol instead of the usual Computer Modern "c" with a circle around it. Is this supposed to happen? I'm using pdfLaTeX with

```
pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (MiKTeX 2.9.7440)
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-06-03>
```

according to my .log file.

Comment: yes, all the textcomp symbols are now already in the kernel. The package is no longer needed.

Comment: Is there a simple way to get the old copyright symbol?

Comment: `\textcircled{c}`.

Comment: On the [“Copyright symbol” Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyright_symbol) I read that the C should be a capital letter.